# SQL syntax error when getting data for a url

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL script:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT user_login FROM wpdb->staff as staff
      join wpdb->users as users on staff.wp_user_id  = users.ID
       where full_name =%s",
    $usernametest
);
$userlogin = $wpdb->query( $query );
```

But I am getting the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '->ab_staff as staff join wpdb->users as users on staff.wp_user_id = users.' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you didn't mean `$wpdb->staff`? By ommitting the `$`, the query now looks for a table called `wpdb->staff`, which isn't valid SQL

As an aside, had you considered using a custom post type/user meta instead of a custom table? Or even a custom taxonomy on users?

Note as well that if you never set `$wpdb->staff`, it won't exist, so you'd be better using the table prefix combined with a hardcoded table name

Comment: You can’t access custom table names as properties on wpdb anyway, can you?

Comment: You can if you put them there, which is what a lot of people do

Comment: thanks all. the following query is working:                                          $query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT user_login FROM wpk6_ab_staff as staff
    join $wpdb->users as users on staff.wp_user_id  = users.ID
     where full_name =%s",
    $usernametest
);
$userlogin = $wpdb->query( $query );                                                                                                                                                                but now for some reason it is returning a numeric value and not the actual user_login. Why could that be?

Comment: I got the answer for why it returned numeric. my code was using: $userlogin = $wpdb->query( $query );       but it should be:  $userlogin = $wpdb->get_var( $query );